# How to put multiple TilePane in a group/list in JavaFx or FXML?

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

I've crumbled the internet to solve my problem but nothing..., So i have a list of TilePane down here

```
     <children>
                <TilePane fx:id="a0" onMouseClicked="#ma0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: black;" />
                <TilePane fx:id="b0" onMouseClicked="#mb0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: black;" GridPane.columnIndex="1" />
                <TilePane fx:id="c0" onMouseClicked="#mc0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: black;" GridPane.columnIndex="2" />
                <TilePane fx:id="d0" onMouseClicked="#md0" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: black;" GridPane.columnIndex="3" />
                <TilePane fx:id="a1" onMouseClicked="#ma1" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: black;" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
    </children>
```

So simply what i want to do is when i click a Button all those Tiles set to disabled all at once! easy right?

In case you didn't get my point... how do i give all these tiles an ID so this ID will represent all those tales "And it must interact as a tile, for example when i do `Id.setVisible(true);` it will effect all the tiles!" Thanks everyone.

maybe not the exact way as i described it but u get the point:)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

why not give id to parent of this tiles, and then just do something like this

```
 pane.getChildren().forEach(node -> node.setDisable(true));
```

and in case you have others childrens in pane - either use "instance of" in forEach, or just group this tiles in another node same way, in Group for example.

Comment: how do i give an id to "parent" for tiles ?

Comment: you have id in your code, same way - just add fx:id to it.

Comment: sorry i'm just a beginner!, where do i add fx:id ?

Comment: i tried to put it in <children fx:id> it gives an error!

Comment: if u mean ID.setVisible(true) it's just an example, so that's the point of my question :p

Comment: no, you have parent for this childrents, something like
`<VBox xmlns:fx="http://javafx.com/fxml">
    <children>
      <TilePane fx:id="a1" onMouseClicked="#ma1" prefHeight="200.0" prefWidth="200.0" style="-fx-background-color: black;" GridPane.rowIndex="1" />
    </children>
</VBox>` and vBox is your parent, but it may be another component, not vBox

Comment: To complete, you can just set `YourParent.setVisible(false)`. With the @AlexG.'s example, it will be `VBox.setVisible(false)`, and all children (not only `TilePane`s) will be hidden. And for the OP, I will add that `visible` and `disable` are two different features (you mention both in your question).